# AWS Static Web Site with SSL not routing properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've completed the instructions located here:  https://dcurt.is/how-to-host-a-static-website-on-aws-with-https

This is to setup s3 buckets for the hosting of a web site, ACM for getting an SSL cert, CloudFront to attached to the ACM and buckets, and Route 53 to the CloudFront instances.

When I go to my domain to view my website, it says "Server Not Found" and I see it is being directed to a URL in the wrong form:  https://http//mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have a misconfigured domain record in Route 53. If you have pointed your domain name to your S3 bucket, change it to point to your CloudFront distribution as mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check the CNAME value of your domain A record and change it from `http//mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to `mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: This worked.  Previously I believe I was plugging in "http://mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" but it was reformatting it without the ":"  Doing your idea of not using anything before the "mydomain.com...." worked!